# "ERROR: Cannot invoke method tokenize() on null object" while versioning of android build using git

Tags: android, git, build.gradle

I am using automatic versioning using git for the first time in my android application and i find myself stuck in an error i have not found an answer to anywhere.
Below is the code that i am using in my gradle :

// Fetch the version according to git latest tag and "how far are we from last tag"

```
    def longVersionName = "git -C ${rootDir} describe --tags --long".execute().text.trim()
    //noinspection GroovyUnusedAssignment
    def (fullVersionTag, versionBuild, gitSha) = longVersionName.tokenize('-')
    def (versionMajor, versionMinor, versionPatch) = fullVersionTag.tokenize('.')

    // Set the version name for server use and display
    def currVersionName = "$versionMajor.$versionMinor.$versionPatch"
    //def currVersionName = "$versionMajor.$versionMinor.$versionPatch.$versionBuild"

    // Set the version name for client viewing
    /*buildConfigField "String", "CLIENT_APP_VERSION", "\"$currVersionName\""*/
    buildConfigField "String", "CLIENT_APP_VERSION", "\"9.0.0\""
    versionName currVersionName

    // Turn the version name into a version code
    versionCode versionMajor.toInteger() * 100000 +
            versionMinor.toInteger() * 10000 +
            versionPatch.toInteger() * 1000 +
            versionBuild.toInteger()

    // Friendly print the version output to the Gradle console
    printf("\n--------" + "VERSION DATA--------" + "\n" +
            "- CODE: " + versionCode + "\n" +
            "- NAME: " + versionName + "\n" +
            "----------------------------\n")
```

Now the problem which is arising is that i am not able to build my project as everytime i try to sync up after adding the above lines of code, i am encountering the following error :

**ERROR: Cannot invoke method tokenize() on null object**

The error is on the line:
**def (versionMajor, versionMinor, versionPatch) = fullVersionTag.tokenize('.')**

I searched for answers for this but i am not able to find any that works.

Comment: is the answer below helping?

Comment: @Lino When I run the "git describe --tags --long" command, i get a tag which is already set to my repo.
So i already have a tag set but still i am encountering this error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your repo has at least one tag with the following pattern x.y.z
To add one:

```
git tag -a 0.1.3 -m "version 0.1.3"
```

now, if you run

```
git describe --tags --long
```

you will get something like this (sha might be different):

```
v0.1.3-0-gb40014a
```

and your gradle will compile. Hope this helps.

Comment: When I run the "git describe --tags --long" command, i get a tag which is already set to my repo. So i already have a tag set but still i am encountering this error.

Comment: could you please post the tag you got? just to check if it has the right format in terms of major, minor etc

Comment: The tag which i get is 7.0.1-334-g02b7d853